# IoC Container accessibility

Tags: mvvm, inversion-of-control, containers, service-locator

I'm wondering if the IoC Container should be referenced only by the class that instantiates and configures it, or if it can be injected into other classes, VMs and VML for example. I'm asking because i saw many people pass it through the ViewModelLocator's construtctor and use it from there.

Is this approach acceptable or to be avoided?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - passing container is Doing it Wrong since it goes against the whole Inversion of Control idea. Here's a few links for you:

Here's [how I use IoC](http://kozmic.pl/2010/06/20/how-i-use-inversion-of-control-containers/) containers ([and part 2](http://kozmic.pl/2010/06/22/how-i-use-inversion-of-control-containers-ndash-pulling-from/))

I also recommend checking out [Windsor's documentation](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx), especially Concepts section which is quite universal (and will be useful to you even if you're not using Windsor).